# accuweather API key is Unauthorized

Tags: json, solidity, smartcontracts

I got an API key from https://developer.accuweather.com/ and I want to use it to get a currentlocation info to use in my smart contract.

When I use it with this format `https://{{api}` or `{{apidev}}.accuweather.com/currentconditions/{version}/{locationKey}{.{format}}?apikey={your key}{&language={language code}}{&details={true or false}}{&getphotos=true or false}`,
I get this error:

`"{"Code":"Unauthorized","Message":"Api Authorization failed","Reference":"/currentconditions/v1/335315.json?apikey=&details=true"}"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please update your question to specify the exact URL you are calling? (And replace the apikey with `redacted` or similar if you wish).
Also, if you can include the code which performs the HTTP request, that might also yield something.